# Filter entities in a one to many relation based on a dynamic value with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Imagine we have the following tables:

```
 codes
| id | code |
-------------
| 1  | 1111 |
| 2. | 2222 |
```

```
 translations
| id | code_id | language |  name                   |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1111    | EN       | Lord of the Rings       |
| 2  | 1111    | ES       | El señor de los anillos |
| 3  | 1111    | FR       | Le Seigneur des Anneaux |
| 4. | 2222    | EN       | Don Quixote.            |
```

And I declare my entities like this:

```
public class Code {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long code.

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Translation> translations;

    ...
}

public class Translation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "code")
    private Code code;

    private String language;

    private String name;

}
```

I am able to retrieve all the translations for an specific code using my `JpaRepository<Location, Long> findAll`, but, I want to be able to "filter" the translations that I receive based on the language. So, as an example, if I want to retrieve the code 1111 (Lord of the Rings), but for Spanish language, then I would get the Code object with the Translation set with one single value, not with the two translations available in the database. Is it possible to achieve this with Spring Data Jpa?